# empty parse dashboard swift

Tags: xcode, heroku, parse-platform

My app uses parse and I've already migrate to heroku + mlab. However, the data's not always there when I open the parse dashboard. I often get the following (when i click into no class will appear)

[image]

My app login a user and display a tableview of uiimages at launch. My app would often try loading but not being able to fetch anything from the server. Every time that happens I checked the dashboard and get the above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update
[image]

i'll try to provide as much info as possible, please tell me if you hv any specific info you want me to share

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes not if I understand correctly? What is the error message in xcode when you can't download objects from the server?

Comment: @mazel tov yes exactly what i meant! sorry for the confusion, but no error message comes up when the simulator cannot download from server. the spinner on the simulator simply disappear after a while and nothing appeared on the tableview. no crash as well.

Comment: parse SDK has really great debugging errors, maybe you just dont print them in debugger window... even if the server would be offline the Parse SDK would give you appropriate error... this is not possible to tell what is wrong if you dont provide anything...

Comment: sorry i'm new to parse and swift, would you mind telling me where to check whether the parse errors are printing? i tried logging into my app with a wrong password when the app's working and it will print out sth like "wrong user info" in my debugger window, is that indicative that i'm printing the errors? i updated my question so that it includes a screenshot of the error on Xcode

Comment: I would check the log in server, I dont know exactly how it works in Heroku but it should be in the log tab in dashboard? Also try to setup VERBOSE=1 before starting the parse server... your picture doesnt say anything important :-)

Comment: okay I'll keep a close eye on heroku logs, thanks for the replies even though i fail to provide much info, really appreciate it!